# Spring Data Mongo - Exclude fields in query from object referenced by @DbRef

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

Say I have two classes as follows:

```
public class Person {

    private String personId;

    private String name;

    private Address address;

}

public class Order {

    private String orderId;

    @DbRef
    private Person customer;

}
```

What I would like to do is run a query against the Order collection but only return specific fields of the linked Person object, something like:

```
public Order findByOrderId(String orderId) {
    Query query = query(where("orderId").is(orderId));
    query.fields().exclude("person.address");
    return operations.findOne(query,Order.class);
}
```

I get the data returned but my exclude argument doesn't seem to be applied if it is across a child object linked via @DbRef. I can exclude attributes of the Order object no problem. The problem I have is that the Person document may get quite large and I want to have control over the network traffic when getting Order objects (i.e. only get data as I need it).

I am using version 1.0.0.M5 of spring-data-mongodb

Does anyone know if this kind of operation is supported?

Many thanks

Joe

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible. The reason is that we transparently translate `DBRef` objects coming from the store using the `fetch()` method which unfortunately does not take a field spec argument. I suggest to open up a ticket in the MongoDB Java driver's bug tracker as well as one for Spring Data MongoDB to let us pick up the added method they might introduce.

A workaround for this could actually be to map the object as `DBRef` inside your domain class and manually resolve it into the actual object by triggering a `findOne(…)` with the nested excludes specified.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround might be to extend AbstractMongoEventListener and override onAfterConvert method and expose it as a Spring Bean

Here you will have access to the Order object and can then set whatever you dont want to null.

You will still get empty fields with default values but the size will be much smaller

Alternatively, you can also write a custom PersonInfo class which has only the fields you require and set it to Order object as well as setting Peson to null