# MongoDB - @DBRef - Is there a way to control the denormalization attributes?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I know that in MongoDB it is possible to denormalize a refernce to another document. By denormalization, I mean selecting which fields will be mentioned inside of the referring (holding) document, except for the id of the referred document.

I found @DBRef in SpringData, which I'm using, but I didn't find the way to configure the fields I want to keep.

For example, I have a Content that has a list of Topics. Both Content and Topic are documents and I would like to implement something like this:

```
public class RelatedToTopicRawData implements IRelationship<RelateToTopicDTO> {

    @DBRef(fields={'_id':1, 'topicName':1})
    private TopicRawData topic;
}
```

Do you know if this is this supported by SpringData?

Thanks
Carmel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not supported as the Java Driver does not yet supported as documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11399380/18122).

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your reply.

Comment: Still not supported? If not, what is common approach?